# can not run javafx mediaplayer in linux fedora

Tags: linux, javafx, fedora

i can not run javafx media player in linux fedora? but run javafx mediaplayer in windows 8.1 ! pleas help me.

I need it for the project that play audio files and video files in Linux.

```
enter code here
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaException;

public class Player extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage)throws FileNotFoundException 
,MediaException {

    File file = new File("/home/mehrdad/Videos/list.mp4");
    Media media = new Media(file.toURI().toString());
    MediaPlayer mediaplayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
    MediaView mediaview = new MediaView(mediaplayer);
    mediaplayer.setAutoPlay(true);
    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(mediaview);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

This is error in runet netbeans :
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2vnR.png)

Comment: What's the error message?  Can you include a stack trace?  A [mcve]?  Details of both your Java environment and Linux versions? Are the formats you want to play [supported](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/media/package-summary.html) and do you have appropriate error reporting in your code (as specified in that link)?  Is it an appropriately configured [certified system configuration for JavaFX media](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdk9certconfig-3761018.html)?   Please put more effort and useful info into your question.

Comment: I added the source code and the error picture when run

Comment: Rather than pasting an image of a stack trace, it is better to copy and paste the text and include the stack trace text (formatted the same way you formatted the code you added) into your question.  And you might still need to provide the other info mentioned in my earlier question to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use java from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html since it's possible that you are using fedora's java which does not inclulde javafx out of the box.

Alternatively you can install `java-1.8.0-openjdk-openjfx` fedora package which should fulfill javafx requirements.

Comment: i use jdk 9 and rpmfussion install

Comment: rpmfusion does not provide jdk. However, according to your stacktrace it seems there is no problem with javafx, but with parameters entering the media player. Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625362/javafx-and-mediaexception-unknown-could-not-create-player which seems to be similar to your problem - there should be file: at the beginning of URL there.

Comment: I see your link is LibAvCodec and LibAvFormat problem. There is no problem with Ubuntu, but Fedora is still an unresolved issue.

Comment: File file = new File("file:////home/list.mp4"); this code error not found video

Comment: It seems that you used four slashes, not three like this: file:///home

Comment: oh sorry i am bad type //// me write file:///home/list.mp4 recive error not found file

Comment: I've got media error with root cause of codec problem here