# Intermittent error while trying to play .wav file with OpenJFX

Tags: java, javafx, media-player, wav

I need an internal .wav (in the source folder) to load into a Media Player without errors.

I got it working yesterday and committed the code with which it worked. Today, rolling back to that commit shows the following error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method

    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!

    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:518)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:421)
    at sokoban@0.0.1/Engine.createPlayer(Engine.java:188)
    at sokoban@0.0.1/Engine.<init>(Engine.java:37)
    at sokoban@0.0.1/initializeGame(Main.java:104)
    at sokoban@0.0.1/start(Main.java:60)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$runLoop$11(GtkApplication.java:277)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!

    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:295)
    at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
    at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
    ... 14 more
Exception running application Main
```

I want to stress that the same code worked fine yesterday.

I found [this](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/331) issue however it seems out of date. Regardless I installed the latest version of ffmpeg available on Arch.

I also found [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26625362/javafx-and-mediaexception-unknown-could-not-create-player) however since it worked earlier, I believe I am referencing the file properly.

Just in case, here is the file structure:

```
main
- java
  - Engine.java
- resources
  - audio.wav
```

and the code that creates the player:

```java
Media music = new Media(getClass().getResource("/audio.wav").toURI().toString());
player = new MediaPlayer(music);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Java#JavaFX%27s_MediaPlayer_constructor_throws_an_exception), that exception might be thrown as a result of some incompatibilities.

Working solution is to install `ffmpeg-compat-55` AUR package.